# A cat tracking a mouse, minigame

Tags: java

Im creating a mini game where a cat have to catch a mouse that moves at random. The idea behind the code is to first move the mouse at random and then check the cats position compared to the mouse. The code worked fine for smaller grids (the first input in CatAndMouse(...)) but with this example (n=100) the mouse started moving below 0. Im sure there would be smarter ways so move the cat, but mainly my question is why does the mouse move too a negative y value? It should only move in a negative y-direction if the current position is greater than 0 and not if its equal to 0?

```
            public class CatAndMouse {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    // runs a test
                    CatAndMouse.runCatAndMouse(100, 7, 88, 98, 13);
                }
                // method here
                public static void runCatAndMouse(int n, int catX, int catY, int mouseX,int mouseY) {
                    // print user input
                    System.out.println(n+" ["+catX+";"+catY+"]"+" ["+mouseX+";"+mouseY+"]");
                    int k = 0;
                    Random random = new Random();
                    // checks for valid input
                    if ( catX < 0 || catY < 0 || mouseX < 0 || mouseY < 0 || n < 0 ||catX > n || catY > n || mouseX > n || mouseY > n) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                    }
                    else {
                        while ( catX != mouseX || catY != mouseY) {
                            k ++;
                            int mouseMovement = random.nextInt(5);
                            if ( mouseMovement == 1 && mouseX < n) {
                                mouseX ++;
                            }
                            else if ( mouseMovement == 2 && mouseY < n) {
                                mouseY ++;
                            }
                            else if ( mouseMovement == 3 && mouseX > 0) {
                                mouseX --;
                            }
                            else if ( mouseMovement == 4 && mouseY > 0) {
                                mouseY --;
                            }

                            // cat
                            if ( catX < mouseX && catY < mouseY){
                                catX ++;
                                catY ++;
                            }
                            else if ( catX > mouseX && catY > mouseY) {
                                catX --;
                                catY --;
                            }
                            else if ( catX < mouseX && catY > mouseY) {
                                catX ++;
                                mouseY --;
                            }
                            else if ( catX > mouseX && catY < mouseY) {
                                catX --;
                                catY ++;
                            }
                            else if ( catX == mouseX+1) {
                                catX ++;
                            }
                            else if ( catY == mouseY+1) {
                                catY ++;
                            }
                            else if ( catX == mouseX-1) {
                                catX --;
                            }
                            else if ( catY == mouseY-1) {
                                catY --;
                            }
                            else if ( catX < mouseX) {
                                catX += 2;
                            }
                            else if ( catY < mouseY) {
                                catY +=2 ;
                            }
                            else if ( catX > mouseX) {
                                catX -= 2;
                                }
                            else if ( catY > mouseY) {
                                catY -= 2;
                            }
                            System.out.println("move "+k+" ["+catX+";"+catY+"]"+" ["+mouseX+";"+mouseY+"]");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: You have a `mouseY--` in one of the `else if` blocks, instead of `catY--`.

Answer (score 1):

Look again at your `else if` block. You have

```
else if ( catX < mouseX && catY > mouseY) {
    catX ++;
    mouseY --;
}
```

Logically, what do you think this is doing? I believe that if you change it from `mouseY--` to `catY--` it will match up with your logic of what the cat and mouse game should be doing.